# Herencia en grails

Tags: grails, herencia

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion en grails y necesito representar una herencia entre dos entidades. El problema radica en que cuando establezco la relacion:

```
class Documento {
static mapping = {
        tablePerHierarchy false
    }

class Tesis extends Documento{
}
```

Cuando genero la vista de la tesis me pide llenar campos que pertenecen a la tabla Documentos y en la base de datos no logro ver la  relacion entre ambas tablas o no entiendo como se establece dicha relacion.

Comment: Hola @Paul, bienvenido al sitio. Una consulta, ¿no sería herencia en Groovy más que herencia en grails? Groovy es el lenguaje de programación utilizado, mientras que Grails es un framework para el lenguaje de programación Groovy. Asimismo, te recomiendo que expliques más detalle de tu problema, por ejemplo cuáles son esos campos no deseados y que proveas más ejemplos para entender mejor la situación.

Comment: A lo que me refiero es a que por ejemplo teniendo 3 clase que heredan de documento, en documento en la base de datos se generan campos pertenecientes a cada una de las tres tablas  y existen ocaciones que hay campos que quedan vacios pues dependiendo de la tabla en la este trabajando,por ejemplo si inserto una tesis en la tabla documento me quedarian campos vacios que pertenecen a las otras dos clases que puedo hacer?

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para reflejar lo que explicas en el comentario.

Comment: No entiendo bien que es lo que quieres, quires tener todos los tipos de documento en una sola tabla o en tres tablas separadas?

Answer (score 3):

Grails por defecto utiliza la representación de la herencia que se llama TPH (table-per-hierarchy).

TPH utiliza un "discriminador" para determinar de qué clase es cada tupla (columna `class`). Como podrán observar no genera varias tablas para cada clase, sino que todos los atributos están en una misma tabla (la tabla padre en este caso `Persona`). Por esta razón, es razonable que ciertos campos queden vacíos, dependiendo qué clase se está insertando.

Lo malo de esta representación es que no permite tener valores `not null`. Es decir si tuvieramos, una clase `Profesor` como la siguiente:

```
class Profesor extends Persona {
    String materiaDictada
    // otras props...

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

y materiaDictada es `not null`, las clases del tipo persona o de tipo alumno no podrían ser guardadas (ya que daría error el INSERT). En este caso se puede usar el enfoque TPS (table_per_subclass) que se puede hacer por medio del [ORM DSL](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/single.html#ormdsl).

La manera de desactivar el comportamiento por defecto de grails, sería lo que se menciona en la pregunta inicial:

```
class Persona {
    ...
    static mapping = {
        tablePerHierarchy false
    }
}
```

Espero sirva.

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Ayudo a esclarecer el problema del amigo Paul...
El tema es el siguiente con otro ejemplo un poco mas practico.

Domain:

```
package com.test

class Persona {
    String nombre
    String apellido
    Date fechaNacimiento

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

---

```
class Alumno extends Persona{

    int legajo
    int curso
    int promedio

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

---

En la base de datos se puede observar lo siguiente al insertar 2 Alumnos nuevos y 1 persona nueva: (El siguiente codigo es un SELECT * from PERSONA)

```
# id, version, apellido, fecha_nacimiento, nombre, class, curso, legajo, promedio
1, 0, Argento, 2016-04-02 00:00:00, Pepe, com.test.Alumno, 3, 33333, 9
2, 0, Argento, 2016-04-02 00:00:00, Moni, com.test.Alumno, 1, 55555, 1
3, 0, Persona 1, 2016-04-02 00:00:00, Nombre Persona 1, com.test.Persona, null, null, null
```

No existe la tabla "ALUMNO" dentro de la BD

Comment: gracias a todos por su ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Por experiencia propia en varios proyectos he visto que no es muy buena idea usar herencia, especialmente si estás trabajando en Grails, los efectos ya los pudiste comprobar, es decir, la base de datos no parece ser muy consistente, eso se debe a que en el modelo relacional no existe forma de plantar cara a una situación de herencia, por lo tanto puedes comenzar a ver tablas con información/estructura extraña e inclusive información duplicada, lo cual no es muy buena idea. Asimismo al momento de desarrollar las pruebas unitarias/integración es un verdadero dolor de cabeza el intentar escribir el código de pruebas si el código base ya contiene casos de herencia. Yo personalmente he desarrollado varios modelos en grails sin embargo en lugar de usar relaciones de herencia he usado relaciones de composición, eso me ha resultado genial, por favor da una revisión al siguiente artículo.

https://devexperto.com/herencia-vs-composicion/

Tu modelo podría ser reestructurado para que use una relación de composición de la siguiente manera:

```
class Documento {
    static constraints {}
}

class Tesis {
    Documento documento
}
```

Dicho modelo de clases puede ser fácilmente representado como 2 tablas dentro de la base de datos.